# Вопрос по функции SetDIBitsToDevice

Tags: winapi

Какое максимальное изображение может вывести на экран эта функция?

Comment: Я выводил карту. 8000 x 8000. Достаточно большое что б система подтормаживала. Для работы с сверх-большими изображениями используйте directX или opengl. Я переписал карту на opengl.

Comment: @nick_n_a, а вы не знаете, из-за чего изображение более 300*300 может не выводиться, и программа сразу после запуска выдает ошибку доступа?

Comment: Или вы не соблюдаете "шапку"  в BITMAPINFO структуре (не правильно указали битность) Или недостаточно место выделили под буфер изображения. Плюс есть "глюк" что windows выравнивает строку изображения по границам двойного слова, т.е. может набежать +300 байт. Покажите ваш код более полно. Возможно не указали буфер или шапку.

Comment: @nick_n_a код: http://pastebin.com/cSfaH7E2 программа создает окно, и после каждого нажатия заполняет квадратную матрицу DIB случайными цветами, и выводит на экран, но если задать размер больше 300, то выдает ошибку доступа при чтении.

Comment: У меня ваша программа дала в BCC ошибку stack overflow. Проверьте настройти стека, т.к.  возможно у вас тоже самое только access violation. Перенёс две строки вверх (в статические переменные) - работает. т.е. так   #include <ctime> const int n = 500;
        RGBQUAD RGB_n[n * n];

Comment: @nick_n_a Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас часный случай. RGB_n обьявлена в стеке. Что не совсем правильно. Выходит в стек нужно выделить 87Kб памяти и более. Нужно увеличить стек, но лучше такие вещи, как обьёмные буферы,  делать или статическими, или через malloc LocalAlloc VirtualAlloc выделять.

Фрагмент вашего кода, где перенёс переменные в глобальную область

```
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
   const int n = 500;
    RGBQUAD RGB_n[n * n];
...
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message,
...
// const int n = 256;  убрать из локальной области
//     RGBQUAD RGB_n[n * n];
```

или ещё можно просто дописать впереди static и никуда не носить, но знать что компилятор перенесёт их в глобальную область данных.

```
 static const int n = 500;
 static  RGBQUAD RGB_n[n * n];
```